# how to make invisible jwplayer code in the page sourcecode

Tags: makefile, jwplayer, invisible, wowza

I set up video lesson site with moodle. I will share my video with jwplayer my code is shown below.

```html
<p>
  <script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer.key="KEY";</script>
</p>
<div id='player'>
  <a href="rtsp://WowzaAdress:554/vod/mp4:Lesson1.mp4"><img src='jwplayer/preview.jpg' alt='RTSP Link' /><br /></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer('player').setup({
id  : 'playerID',
fallback: false,
width: '920', height: '518',
image: 'jwplayer/preview.jpg',
sources: [{
file: "http://WowzaAdress:1935/vod/smil:Lesson1.smil/jwplayer.smil?protocol=rtmpe"
},{
file: "http://WowzaAdress:1935/vod/Lesson1.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
}],
rtmp: {
bufferlength: 3
},
});
</script>
```

I want to hide this code when users view with right click "Page source".
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

So then you get:

```
<script>
<!--
document.write(unescape("%3Cp%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20src%3D%22jwplayer/jwplayer.js%22%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%3E%20jwplayer.key%3D%22KEY%22%3B%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20id%3D%27player%27%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22rtsp%3A//WowzaAdress%3A554/vod/mp4%3ALesson1.mp4%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%27jwplayer/preview.jpg%27%20alt%3D%27RTSP%20Link%27%20/%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javascript%22%3E%0Ajwplayer%28%27player%27%29.setup%28%7B%0Aid%20%20%3A%20%27playerID%27%2C%0Afallback%3A%20false%2C%0Awidth%3A%20%27920%27%2C%20height%3A%20%27518%27%2C%0Aimage%3A%20%27jwplayer/preview.jpg%27%2C%0Asources%3A%20%5B%7B%0Afile%3A%20%22http%3A//WowzaAdress%3A1935/vod/smil%3ALesson1.smil/jwplayer.smil%3Fprotocol%3Drtmpe%22%0A%7D%2C%7B%0Afile%3A%20%22http%3A//WowzaAdress%3A1935/vod/Lesson1.mp4/playlist.m3u8%22%0A%7D%5D%2C%0Artmp%3A%20%7B%0Abufferlength%3A%203%0A%7D%2C%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%3C/script%3E"));
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thank for your answer. i tried this but ip adress still visible. and videos are not playable anymore

Comment: somebody help me, please

Comment: i set up online lesson web site with moodle. i was using eFront before but eFront did'nt show my content with right click(source view) how could be possible? i want hide my server adress like this

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean?